# OpenLayers 3, area intersection between geometries

Tags: javascript, intersection, openlayers-3

I'm evaluating if OpenLayers3 would serve us to develop some tools we need on our day to day basis and I'm getting stuck with one feature that I supose it has to exist but I cannot find information about.

I need to know if OpenLayers will allow us to calculate the intersection area between two polygons.

We'll load different layers on the map. Usually a layer with terrain separation and other one with terrain classes.

We'll need to stablish how much terrain of each class there is in each separation, and my best shoot to that is by intersecting polygons in different layers.

I'm being unable to find examples or info about a feature like this in OpenLayers3 documentation.

If anyone of you knows a better approach to calculate land type amounts in a parcel I'll be also glad to know it.

EDIT: What about implementing a polygon collission algorithm? Would [Sutherland-Hodgman Algorithm](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sutherland-Hodgman_polygon_clipping) do the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenLayers 3 itself does not provide functions to calculate the intersection between polygons. But it is relatively straightforward to use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) with ol3:

```
var polygon1 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon(...));
var polygon2 = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon(...));

var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var intersection = format.readFeature(
    turf.intersect(
        format.writeFeatureObject(polygon1),
        format.writeFeatureObject(polygon2)));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d6o81vc7/

Comment: This seems very promising I'll be probably unable to invest time into it in the next days, but as soon as I can confirm it fits to our needs I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Took me quite some time to realize that you have to transform from the OL-Feature format to GeoJSON in order to use it with Turf.js. EDIT: still works with OL6