# Openlayers - Avoid and adjust overlapping polygons

Tags: openlayers, polygon, turfjs

I have a project that uses Openlayers in order to draw, edit and show multiple polygons. One of the features I want to add to the project is the automatic avoiding of overlapping features.

When a user draws a new features. The application should check if any of the already existing features is being overlapped by the new feature. This is already available thanks to the Turf.js library: [Stackoverflow discussion on overlapping features.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29654865/openlayers-3-area-intersection-between-geometries)

The next step I want to add is the ability to automatically cut off and remove the excess areas from the new feature that overlaps the existing ones. I have searched on the Turf.js documentation but I cannot a function that does that.

Comment: Where polygons intersect you could use turf.difference

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the fast answer! I think this might be the solution. I will try it out!

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the answer! I have found a fitting solution combining both the intersect and difference methods from the Turf.js library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Mike I have created a solution that works. I loop over all features that exist in the VectorLayer. I first check if the feature is indeed a Polygon. Then I convert the features into Turf Polygon objects and check if they intersect. If they intersect I use the difference function from Turf and set the coordinates of the feature to the generated Polygon.

```
  const removeOverlappingAreasWithExistingFeatures = (feature) => {
    const format = new GeoJSON();

    store.state.layers.drawingLayer.getFeatures().forEach((existingFeature) => {
      if (
        existingFeature.getGeometry().getType() !== 'Polygon' ||
        !existingFeature.get('description') ||
        existingFeature.get('description') === feature.get('description')
      )
        return;

      var featurePoly = format.writeFeatureObject(feature);
      var existingFeaturePoly = format.writeFeatureObject(existingFeature);

      const intersection = turf.intersect(featurePoly, existingFeaturePoly);
      if (intersection) {
        var difference = turf.difference(featurePoly, intersection);

        difference.geometry.coordinates =
          difference.geometry.coordinates.filter(
            (coordinate) => coordinate.length > 0
          );

        feature.setGeometry(format.readFeature(difference).getGeometry());
      }
    });

    return feature;
  };
```

Comment: You should not assume the difference result is a polygon.  If the intersection cuts the new polygon into two parts it will be a multipolygon.  Using `format.writeFeatureObject()` and `format.readFeature().getGeometry()` as in https://codesandbox.io/s/vector-layer-forked-jb3i4?file=/main.js would be safer.  Note that turf can return multipolygons with empty polygons which need to be removed as it breaks OpenLayers.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the good tips! I have updated the code with your suggestions. Can you please check if I have correctly implemented your suggestions?

Comment: If were are empty polygons in a multipolygon result they would break readFeature, so they would need to be removed earlier.  I suspect that is only a problem when reducing existing multipolygons - such as Canada in the example where the arctic islands are removed.

Comment: @Mike I have updated the code. Now I do the filter on the turf object and then I convert it to a Openlayers feature.